# How to process large scale sparse data at high speed in R

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics

I have a large scale data `sample_dt` here, Its row is chromosome pos and col is sample name(id), Its my input with about `3 billion` row (pos) and 3000 col (sample).

For next process, I need some group attrib, Its calculate from samples in a group, I got a table `attrib_dt` by compute this attrib group by group at every pos (one sample only included in one group), then I combine `sample_dt` and  `attrib_dt` to a larger `data.table` `Combine_dt`

My tasks is use value in `sample_dt` and group attribs with a known function `f(x)` to calcuate a score, get a new data.table with score per pos per sample and ready for next step.

Here is my workflow:

[image]

My issue is:

(1) The scale of the data seems too large, I loaded about 1/5 of the data for processing, it seems to consume close to 200GB of memory, which seems too large, in fact, sample_dt is a sparse matrix, most of the values are 0, whether there is any optimization method

(2) To speed things up, I want to use the R property of vectorization operations to compute the output matrix. I wrote a Rcpp function to compute f(x). How should I organize the data is better?

Comment: I added bio tag as I am guessing "sample_dt" is a VCF file and attrib_dt is an annotation file, there might be other command line type existing tools for this. What is the f(x) function is doing?

Comment: Consider splitting by chrom, and sample groups.

Comment: f(x) is a (list of) formula in publications without known software. It evaluates the probability of a locus coming from a specific ancestral genome by using the individual genotype parameters, and the genetic parameters of the population (score) (and other info we known).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm being asked to make some kind of interactive tool, and even though I split it by chromosome, I also must load it when the user visits the site, it's too large, it seems to have to be in memory

Comment: I think you may want a database(-alike) approach to select outside of memory.  If all you need is one file it could be as simple as sqlite, or it could be duckdb so that you can query unique ids and select by them. Or you could go with a single-cell solution -- I work at TileDB and we have VCF solutions as well as dedicated single-cell code for R and Python, see https://github.com/single-cell-data/TileDB-SOMA

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was wondering if I could convert the data into a database like sqllite to achieve this purpose. It seems that there are some difficulties in how to convert  and deal with the data structure in the database

Comment: Another option might be HDF5 (through [`HDF5Array`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/HDF5Array.html)) that implements Bioconductor's `DelayedArray` interface, and is particularly useful if you need to run matrix ops with on-disk objects. However, the DB approach Dirk mentions may be more suitable for the dashboard application described.